# Sortable Grid-like control for large data sets?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, dataset, gui-construction

I've been using a roll-your-own function for a while that's a wrapper around Grid which adds a couple things I always use, like headers, dynamic sorting, filtering, and clipping (only showing the first and last $n$ entries). Like so:

[image: screenshot]

This works pretty well, but every once in a while, I have to deal with larger tables. In my experience, once Mathematica starts trying to deal with Tables/Lists getting up toward 100k entries, performance plummets.

So my question is whether there is something I've overlooked that's already built into Mathematica that serves more or less this same purpose, but without the performance hit. And if there's not a ready-made Grid-like control, is there a better way to store and access the data (short of using an actual database), like maybe one where you can define data types up front so it's not so bloated?

Comment: tried [TableView](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableView.html)?

Comment: Oh, sweet. That's new-ish I take it? I'll have to give it a try, but the doc sounds promising, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely much snappier overall... sadly, the scroll bar seems to be all but useless when you have thousands of entries.

Comment: I'd love to see more large-data-navigation (and large-output-navigation) features in mathematica. What you have looks nice! Besides applying `Dataset` and using that view, though, I don't know any other built-in ones.